# Updated State using React Hooks not causing a re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am currently making a UI where I want to display the results of a collection of NFT's that I grab using the Alchemy SDK. I am currently displaying a default collection of NFTs using getServerSideProps and passing down the result of the API call as props to the main Home component. The way I have structured my application is that I have a main Home component that displays a Gallery component where I pass down the collection of NFT's in the state of the parent (Home) component. The Gallery component then renders a Card component for each NFT by mapping through it's  state and accessing properties of each NFT object (image and tokenId).

I am currently trying to implement a search bar function where users can input a contract address and the results of the collection will be updated depending on the collection that the user searched for. I can currently get the state of the parent component to be updated depending on the user search input and this is reflected in the state when I open up the React Dev Tools. I can also pass this updated state down to the childComponent. However, the Gallery Component (Gallery) does not re-render because although the props have been updated, the changes are not reflected in it's state even after implementing the useEffect method within the component. I am wondering how to change the state of the Child component (Gallery) using the updated props and render those changes in the Gallery.

Parent Component

- I am currently updating the state of the Home Component in the handleSubmit() function which is an async function that runs when a user submits their search input.
- These changes are currently reflected in the state of the parent component and passed down as props to the Gallery component

```
const Home = ({results}: {results: object}) => {
  const [nfts, setNfts] = useState(results.nfts);
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    setNfts(results.nfts);
  }, [])

  const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newCollection = await findNftsByContractAddress(userInput);
    const newResults = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newCollection))

    setNfts(newResults.nfts);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Shibuya Take Home</title>
      </Head>

      <NavBar />
      <form action="submit" >
        <input type="text" className="search-bar" onChange={e => setUserInput(e.target.value)} />
        <input type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}/>
      </form>
      {/* Search Bar Component Goes Here */}
      {/* Title text */}
      <Gallery key={nfts} nfts={nfts}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

export const getServerSideProps = async() => {
  // function is going to need to take in user input and replace the bored ape yacht club with user address
  const boredApeYachtClubRaw = await findNftsByContractAddress("0xed5af388653567af2f388e6224dc7c4b3241c544");
  const results = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(boredApeYachtClubRaw))

  return {props: {
    results
  }}
}
```

Gallery Component (Child)

- The current issue is that I cannot get the updated props to reflect in the Gallery component. The state is never changed and thus the components on the page never re-render and display the original collection of NFTs that were passed down on the first render.
- I can get the changes to be reflected if I directly render the cards using the props passed down to the child component --> but this is not a good practice as some collection will have missing elements.

  - I eventually need to create a function to filter through the props and create a new collection (array) that only contain NFT's with valid images (nft.media[0].gateway sometimes returns undefined)

```
export default function Gallery({nfts}: {nfts: object[]}) {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [collection, setCollection] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTitle(nfts[0].contract.name);
        setDescription(nfts[0].description);
        setCollection(nfts);
    }, [title, description, collection])

    return(
        <div className="gallery-container">
            <h1 className="gallery-title">{nfts[0].contract.name}</h1>
            <p className="gallery-description">{nfts[0].description}</p>
            <div className="cards-container">
                {nfts.map(nft => {
                    return (
                        <Card image={nft.media[0].gateway} tokenId={nft.tokenId}/>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

- NFT object that I get back

```
0: 
contract: 
{address: '0xed5af388653567af2f388e6224dc7c4b3241c544', name: 'Azuki', symbol: 'AZUKI', totalSupply: '10000', tokenType: 'ERC721'}
description
: 
""
media
: 
[{…}]
rawMetadata
: 
{name: 'Azuki #0', image: 'https://ikzttp.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmYDvPAXtiJg7s8JdRBSLWdgSphQdac8j1YuQNNxcGE1hg/0.png', attributes: Array(7)}
timeLastUpdated
: 
"2022-10-30T14:58:51.119Z"
title
: 
"Azuki #0"
tokenId
: 
"0"
tokenType
: 
"ERC721"
tokenUri
: 
{raw: 'https://ikzttp.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmQFkLSQysj94s5GvTHPyzTxrawwtjgiiYS2TBLgrvw8CW/0', gateway: 'https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qm
```

Comment: Why have you declared `title`, `description`, and `collection` state values in the `Gallery` component? They are not used. The `Gallery` component appears to be correctly accessing the `nfts` prop directly. You probably ***don't*** want to use the `nfts` object as a React key though. Other than this it's not clear what any issue may be. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this render issue that we could inspect live?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the dependency array you're passing into the `useEffect` hook.

You're passing in the state variables within the child `Gallery` component, each of which is getting the actual values from the parent `Home` component, most likely *after* the first render.

By the time the child component mounts, they still have the values they are initialized with. The `useEffect` hook is waiting for these state variables to change before triggering again, which never happens because the logic to update them is inside the hook itself.

What you should have in the dependency array is the `nfts` array.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTitle(nfts[0].contract.name);
    setDescription(nfts[0].description);
    setCollection(nfts);
}, [nfts]);
```

Now, we could argue that the `props` for the child component (and hence `nfts`) would be available on initial mount, but it is not clear from your code as to where the `nfts` array actually comes from. It is passed to the parent `Home` component inside *its* `props`, so it could be coming from an API response elsewhere, in which case there's got to be a delay before the array is available.

It's surprising that your app does not crash when `useEffect` is running for the first time with stuff like `nfts[0].contract.name`, but again, I don't know how `results` is initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the response and results is being initialized inside of the Home component in the getServerSideProps method. It's being returned and passed down as a prop to the Home component. Then I'm initializing the state of the parent component using the nfts array and passing this down as a prop to the child component.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure what the *real* initial value for `nfts` (or `results`) would be, because you're passing in the array from the API response into the parent's `useState` hook as the *initial value*, which kind of an anti-pattern. I have no idea what the value would be before the API response comes through. Maybe someone with more experience/knowledge than me could answer that. My solution, still, is to use `nfts` as dependency in your child component's `useEffect`